# Identifying some cyclic subgroup

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, homological-algebra

Is there a fast way to argue that (for $a,b>1$ integers) the set of all $x\in\mathbf{Z}/b\mathbf{Z}$ with $ax=0$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}/{gcd(a,b)}\mathbf{Z}$? Maybe by counting the elements, since if cyclic groups are determined by their cardinality?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they two groups are both cyclic group of order (a,b).

Comment: But why is the first one of order $(a,b)$? that's the whole point of my question ;)

Comment: Well, the first is the number of solution of the equation $ax\equiv 0 (mod ~b)$, which is just (a,b).